# Tkinter / Python grid layout with listboxes

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, tkinter

I'm having some trouble getting everything to line up properly using a grid with Tkinter and Python. I want to have the menu bar at the very top, and then two listboxes (one on each side), with a couple buttons between them in the middle of the window.

Currently, both listboxes are appearing on the bottom right side of the window, and the buttons are in the upper left corner, overlapping the menu buttons.

How do I deal with the grid layout of a listbox considering their size. Can they occupy more than one grid cell? For example, if I place a listbox in (row=1, column = 1) and another in row (row = 1, column = 2), would Tkinter automatically widen the cell so that it's the width of the listbox, or would it just overlap the listboxes?

```
def __init__(self,root):
    self.frame = Frame(root, width=500)
    self.frame.pack()
    self.BuildMainWindow(self.frame)
    self.ListboxSet = 0 
    self.frame.grid()
    return

#displays the menu bar and options
def BuildMainWindow(self, frame):
    menubar = Frame(frame,relief=RAISED,borderwidth=1)
    menubar.pack()

    mb_file = Menubutton(menubar,text='file')
    mb_file.menu = Menu(mb_file)
    mb_file.menu.add_command(label='open', command = self.openfile)
    mb_file.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    mb_edit = Menubutton(menubar,text='edit')
    mb_edit.menu = Menu(mb_edit)
    mb_edit.grid(row=1, column = 3)

    mb_file['menu'] = mb_file.menu
    mb_edit['menu'] = mb_edit.menu

#upon selecting a directory from the menu and listboxes/buttons are created
def BuildListbox(self, directory):
    self.listbox1 = Tkinter.Listbox()
    self.listbox2 = Tkinter.Listbox()
    self.listbox1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.listbox2.grid(row=2 ,column=10)
    self.listbox2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e:SortActions.GetWindowIndex(self,e))
    self.listbox2.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e:SortActions.MoveWindowItem(self,e))

    i = 0
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        self.listbox1.insert(i, filename)
        i = i + 1

    self.bAddToListTwo = Button(self.frame, text = "->", command = lambda:SortActions.AddToListTwo(self,self.listbox1.curselection()))
    self.bAddToListTwo.grid(row=5, column = 5)
    self.bAddAll = Button(self.frame, text = "Add All To Playlist", command = lambda:SortActions.AddAllFiles(self))
    self.bAddAll.grid(row=6, column = 5)
    self.bRemoveFromListTwo = Button(self.frame, text = "Remove From Playlist", command = lambda:SortActions.RemoveFromListTwo(self,self.listbox2.curselection()))
    self.bRemoveFromListTwo.grid(row=7, column = 5)
    self.bSavePlaylist = Button(self.frame, text = "Save Playlist", command = lambda:SortActions.SaveList(self))
    self.bSavePlaylist.grid(row=8, column = 5)
```

**update - I got it to work. As I suspected, I had some weird frame configuration during the initialization.**

```
def __init__(self,root):
    self.BuildMainWindow(root)
    self.ListboxSet = 0 
    return

#displays the menu bar and options
def BuildMainWindow(self, root):
    menubar = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    # Create a menu button labeled "File" that brings up a menu
    filemenu = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)

    # Create entries in the "File" menu
    # simulated command functions that we want to invoke from our menus
    filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command=self.openfile)
    filemenu.add_separator(  )
    filemenu.add_command(label='Quit', command=sys.exit)

#upon selecting a directory from the menu and listboxes/buttons are created
def BuildListbox(self, directory):
    self.listbox1 = Tkinter.Listbox()
    self.listbox2 = Tkinter.Listbox()
    self.listbox1.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan = 4, columnspan = 5)
    self.listbox2.grid(row=1 ,column=15, rowspan = 4, columnspan = 5)
    self.listbox2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e:SortActions.GetWindowIndex(self,e))
    self.listbox2.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e:SortActions.MoveWindowItem(self,e))

    i = 0
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        self.listbox1.insert(i, filename)
        i = i + 1

    self.bAddToListTwo = Button(text = "->", command = lambda:SortActions.AddToListTwo(self,self.listbox1.curselection()))
    self.bAddToListTwo.grid(row=1, column = 6)
    self.bAddAll = Button(text = "Add All To Playlist", command = lambda:SortActions.AddAllFiles(self))
    self.bAddAll.grid(row=2, column = 6)
    self.bRemoveFromListTwo = Button(text = "Remove From Playlist", command = lambda:SortActions.RemoveFromListTwo(self,self.listbox2.curselection()))
    self.bRemoveFromListTwo.grid(row=3, column = 6)
    self.bSavePlaylist = Button(text = "Save Playlist", command = lambda:SortActions.SaveList(self))
    self.bSavePlaylist.grid(row=4, column = 6)
```

Comment: Are you aware thre are better ways to create a menubar? (Ie: `menu` option on root wondow and toplevel window)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tkinter widgets *can* occupy more than 1 grid-cell, but you need to manage the layout yourself using the `columnspan` and `rowspan` keywords to `.grid`.

For example, to get the layout:

```
 --------------------------------------------
 |      Button1      |  Button2 |           |
 --------------------------------  Button3  |
 | Label1  |  Label2 |  Label3  |           |
 --------------------------------------------
```

You'd need to do something like:

```
Button1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
Button2.grid(row=0,column=2)
Button3.grid(row=0,column=4,rowspan=2)
Label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
Label2.grid(row=1,column=1)
Label3.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

*very minimal script*

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
Button1 = tk.Button(root,text="Button1")
Button2 = tk.Button(root,text="Button2")
Button3 = tk.Button(root,text="Button3")
Label1 = tk.Label(root,text="Label1")
Label2 = tk.Label(root,text="Label2")
Label3 = tk.Label(root,text="Label3")

Button1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
Button2.grid(row=0,column=2)
Button3.grid(row=0,column=4,rowspan=2)
Label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
Label2.grid(row=1,column=1)
Label3.grid(row=1,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do I treat the menu the same way or does it by default always get placed on the top?

Comment: Not sure about Menu's -- I'll need to look at the docs a bit.  However, your code is a little weird anyway as it appears that you're mixing `.grid` and `.pack`  (e.g. `self.frame` gets packed and gridded -- This can lead to very strange and likely undefined behavior) -- Note that I think you can mix `grid` and `pack` in the same application, just not in the same frame/toplevel.

Comment: According to [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm), the menu is always placed at the top of the current toplevel (except on OS-X)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I didn't even realize that I was still using .pack for the menubar. I changed it to .grid and now the buttons aren't overlapping it anymore. Do I still need to pack the frame, or can I use .grid for that too?

Comment: @user1104854 -- You can grid frames too :)  (I almost always use the grid geometry manager -- I don't like pack as it just doesn't seem to make sense to me :)

Comment: Your listboxes have no master frame -- Thus, they're being bound to the root frame.  Perhaps you want `self.listbox1 = Tkinter.Listbox(self.frame)`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately they're still appearing on the right side. They appear diagonal to the menu. When I included the buttons, those appeared diagonal too

Comment: @user1104854: get out some paper and a pencil, draw a grid, and place your widgets in it. That's the easiest way to solve layout problems when you're just learning.

Comment: @mgilson I got it to work. If you're curious I updated my code above. I had some weird issues going on with the way I created my frame.